# How to Add Virtual Network Interface Mavericks

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I like to have a separate virtual network interface on Mavericks, so I can have static IP between the Guest to Host setup of VirtualBox. In xUbuntu, i could do that by updating /etc/network/interfaces:

```
#The secondary network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 10.88.12.4
netmask 255.0.0.0
```

How to do the same in Mac Mavericks? I did try using 'system preferences'->Networks->Actions Menu->Manage Virtual Network Interfaces->Add New VLAN, however, it is giving 'Status: Cable Unplugged'. How to make virtual network interface on Maverick? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The solution was letting VirtualBox create the virtual network interface by creating "Host Only Network"   by going VirtualBox VM -> Preferences -> Network -> Host Only Networks -> Add New and set up the IP/Subnet at that time

Afterwards, check the new virtual network interface by typing "ifconfig" in the command line. It will desiplay something like:

```
vboxnet0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 
    inet 10.88.12.0 netmask 0xff000000 broadcast 10.255.255.255
```